# Erro com unexpected token JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql, hql

Fiz um um select JPQL porém estou tendo este erro:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 151 [select pes, pEnd from digifred.model.global.Pessoas pes, digifred.model.global.PessoasEnderecos pEnd where pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId and where pEnd.entidade.idEntidade=:parametroId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:288) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Meu método está assim:

```
@Query( value="select pes, pEnd from Pessoas pes, PessoasEnderecos pEnd where pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId and where pEnd.entidade.idEntidade=:parametroId" )
    public  Collection<Pessoas>  encontrar(@Param("parametroId") Long usuarioEntidade);
```

Comment: você esta usando spring ?

Comment: Sim, estou usando Spring boot

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Só a forma do seu parâmetro ta errado

: #{#parametroId.idEntidade}

: ?#{[parametroId]} Por ser long

Comment: Se puder posta como resposta ali junto com o meu código pra eu ver melhor..

Comment: Você ta usando sintaxe da HQL, só usar o JPQL dentro do seu código. Ta corrido no trampo, mas espera que vou arrumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa é sua query, com algumas quebras de linhas a mais:

```sql
select pes, pEnd
from Pessoas pes, PessoasEnderecos pEnd
where pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId
and where pEnd.entidade.idEntidade=:parametroId
```

Observe esse `and where` nessa última linha. Isso está errado, era para ser apenas `and`. Ou seja, retire a segunda palavra `where`:

```sql
select pes, pEnd
from Pessoas pes, PessoasEnderecos pEnd
where pes.entidade.idEntidade = :parametroId
and pEnd.entidade.idEntidade=:parametroId
```